# Why is a horizontal scroll bar appearing if none of the elements are wider than the 960px container?

Tags: css, layout

Everything is wrapped in a div with an `id="main_wrap"`

the main wrap has this style:

```
#main_wrap{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:960px;
  position:relative;
}
```

Since everything is wrapped inside of this div, I don't understand why a horizontal scroll bar would appear at the bottom.

Comment: Are you counting the paddings? It is hard to find the problem unless you post a link to the site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try add overflow hidden:

```
#main_wrap{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That should work (but is hacky).

Comment: That will work by "hacking" the code, but it is better to fix the issue that create the overflow in first place.

Comment: this is a hack, not a solution

Comment: Since the question is specific to horizontal-scroll bar, it's better to add overflow-x: hidden; to avoid vertical scroll bar from not being scrolled which is also a hack FYI.

Comment: @BalasubramaniM: Well, that's *slightly* better than what's suggested in this answer, but still doesn't help with the "why" question that was actually asked.

Answer (score 34):

If any of the children have borders, padding (or sometimes margins) applied to them, that adds to the width and height. Using `overflow: hidden;` would avoid the scroll bars. But, if something has too much width, you probably want to find where it is coming from to avoid possible problems in the future.

Note that you may be able to use `box-sizing: border-box` to prevent borders and padding from adding additional width (or height). This is particularly useful when you are using something like `width: 100%`, but `width: 100%` also isn't necessary in most cases - elements with `display: block` applied will fill the width by default AND keep padding and borders from adding additional width.

For example:

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

div {
  background: #111;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 1em; /* This doesn't add to width - still at 100% width */
  border: 2px solid #5e5;  /* This also doesn't add to width - still at 100% width */
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

Comment: That's really interesting. I hadn't heard of `box-sizing` — maybe it came with CSS3. I found an interesting article at https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/. I was wondering if you might agree that CSS is far more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: Yes and no, I suppose? It's getting simpler to use as new standard features come out and gain cross-browser support (ex. `display: grid`), but old features need to stick around for compatibility, so it seems necessarily bloated to me.

Comment: It's also not complicated enough, at times. Using a preprocessor adds complexity in one way, but it's common practice - in most projects, it leads to simpler, more maintainable code than pure CSS.

Answer (score 3):

If the elements are side by side and have a combined width or , as BDawg says margins or paddings, that cause it to exceed 960px a scroll bar could appear.  Post your entire code and we can figure it out very quickly.  Hiding the overflow should work but it would not really explain why the scroll bar is appearing.  Giving us your entire markup will help find the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you've left any DOM elements unseen which occupies the extra width. it's better to find and fix the children than to use  `overflow:hidden` . overflow:hidden will hide the scroll bar if user zooms in the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you change width to 100% it helped you, but if you don't want, 
 just try add external `<div style="width:100%"></div>` 
 like this:

```
    <div style="width:100%">
       <div class="main_wrap">
          %your content%
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Working 100%

if you are using bootstrap it takes
margin-left & right 15px (or) -15px

---

you need to change 15px to 0px

### Example

```
.main_wrap .row{
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
}
```